# How to get List data to another place in C#

Tags: c#, list, csv

I created a List.Now I want to know How I call this List object after foreach loop.I want to get pass column's whole data (Date and Pass column)to print and want to get  (if pass==True) data only.So how I send those results to another .csv file..How I do that.please hep.

this is my list as follows;

```
private void btnFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<DrawNew> ObserveData = new List<DrawNew>(); // List to store all available DrawNew objects from the CSV

    // Loops through each lines in the CSV
    foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(outputFilePath.Text).Skip(1)) // .Skip(1) is for skipping header
    {
        string[] valuesCsvLine = line.Split(',');
        DrawNew mngInstance = new DrawNew();

        mngInstance.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(valuesCsvLine[0], dateFormatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
        mngInstance.Pass = (valuesCsvLine[1] == "TRUE" ? true : false);

        ObserveData.Add(mngInstance);     
    }
}
```

This is my class for store data.

```
class DrawNew
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } // property to store Date 
    public bool Pass { get; set; } // property to store ChargeMode
 }
```

Comment: What specifically are you struggling with.

Comment: You can do `foreach (var item in ObserveData) { /* process item */ }`

Comment: @PeterB.thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @PeterB,Sir can you say how I pass this two column for another .csv file .I want to get that two column and pass that data,.in here I wrote  `StringBuilder csvcontent= new StringBuilder(); csvcontent.AppendLine("Date,Pass");                      
string path = @"D:\C1.csv ";
File.AppendAllText(path, csvcontent.ToString());`this is not working.can you give any answer for create that selected column data to another .csv file

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a linq query to select the data you want, something like

```
var csv = new StringBuilder();
csv.AppendLine("Date,Pass"); // Header, skip if it is not needed
var myQueriedList = ObserveData.Where(p => p.Pass == true);
foreach (var value in myQueriedList )
{
    //comma deliminated csv
    csv.AppendFormat("{0},{1}", value.Date.ToString(dateFormatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), value.Pass.ToString().ToUpper()).AppendLine();
}
File.WriteAllText(filePath, csv.ToString());
```

I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: ,thank you for your help.In here I want to add this two  columns(Date & Pass).If you have time please tell how I add two columns in new .csv file.thank you.

Comment: the code above should add the two columns(Date & Pass) to a .csv file, `myQueriedList` should return all list items with `pass== true`, in the foreach loop you need to just select the data you want (at the moment it is selecting date and pass and formatting them, if the answer works for you please mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Use this loop--

foreach(var listOfItem In ObserveData)

{

listOfItem.ColoumData;

}